# Convert post title to CamelCase

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to convert a post title to CamelCase to create a twitter hashtag, I'm using strip but its returning a object instead I dont know if this is the right way?

```
# views.py
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        raise Http404

    form_class = PostCreateForm
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.creator = request.user
            instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)
            instance.hashtag = instance.title.strip()
            instance.save()


            slug = slugify(instance.title)
            return redirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    else:
        form = form_class()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "posts/post_create.html", context)
```

Which returns `<built-in method strip of unicode object at 0x031ECB48>` in the template var, the result I'm looking for is like this `MyPostTitle` into the template

```
    # Template view
    <h3>#{{instance.hashtag|title}}</h3>
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: Could you show your Post model definition? Thanks.

Comment: I've added the Post model

Comment: Okay, may be it's me missing something or didn't have enough coffee. Try removing the pyc files and restarting the server - it really looks like it's running as `instance.title.strip` instead of `instance.title.strip()`.

Comment: Cool, I deleted the pyc files and it works, but now the hashtag still has whitespaces `My Post Title` instead of `MyPostTitle` any way to fix this

Comment: Strip returns a list. Added an answer that also deletes punctuation and capitalize the words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = "foo baz bar"
>>> "".join([s.capitalize() for s in a.rsplit()])
>>> FooBazBar
```

To save:

```
import re
r = re.compile("[/!/?,:.;-]")

t = r.sub(" ",instance.title) # clear punctuation
instance.hashtag = "".join([s.capitalize() for s in t.rsplit()])
```

Comment: This works great I had to change `form` to `instance`.hashtag its showing camelcase

Answer (score 4):

`strip` only removes the whitespace from the beginning or end of the string (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip). You might use

```
instance.hashtag = instance.title.replace(' ', '')
```

As a side note, it might be cleaner to add this functionality as a method to your model class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def hashtag(self):
        if self.title is not None:
            return self.title.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's unicode class also has a `title()` method, meaning you may do:

```
$ python3
>>> 'foo bar baz'.title()
'Foo Bar Baz'
>>> 'foo bar baz'.title().replace(' ', '')
'FooBarBaz'
```

Note that the order of `.title().replace()` is important!

Comment: Thanks, I think this one is even better cause I don't have to python `import re` I can use title() method.